# Ruby On Rails app's hosting on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, hosting

I am new at this so I will ask one straight question.

I have Paperclip plugin on my project, so I had to install ImageMagick on my windows machine.
So If i want to deploy on server my app does I need to install on my server ImageMagick too ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Wherever you expect to host & execute your Paperclip plugin will also need to have ImageMagick installed + any additional image delegates (libpng, libtiff &tc).